# Two terms about Flink

Tags: apache-flink

Can anyone help verify the terms for the following items?

- Duration between the event time and ingestion time for an event. I made a term called "queued time".
- Duration between the current timestamp and the time of the last event in a window that is in progress. I made a term called "idle time".

Are the terms I made correct? Your suggestion is high appreciated.

I'm currently involved in writing some documentation on Flink.

Answer (score 1):

I think those terms work well in some contexts, but in general I have some reservations. For example, consider batch processing, or (re-)ingesting historic data in a streaming application. Does "queued time" meaningfully describe the duration between the event time and ingestion time this situation? Maybe, maybe not. Or consider the situation when starting to recover after an outage: at that moment the difference between the current timestamp and the last event in a window isn't due to an idle source, but is instead due to the downtime.

In the first case it feels like your interest is in describing and measuring different sources of latency. In that context I think it makes sense to distinguish between the *publishing delay* (the time between event creation and the storage of the event in the queue), the *ingestion delay* (the time between publishing into the message broker and subsequent ingestion into Flink) and *processing delay*, which is the time is takes Flink to process the event. Processing delays are caused by watermarking, serialization, network buffering, checkpoint barrier alignment, two-phase commits, etc.

I'm less clear on the intention behind *idle time*, but perhaps that could be defined as the time elapsed at the flink source since the last event was ingested, or relative to any specific operator instance, the time since it last received an event.

Comment: Thanks David. I got what you mean. But do you have any suggested terms?